# React-Table not rendering data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am trying to render some data in a react-table component however the data doesn't load. I have tested out with dummy data of the exact same format and it works fine. However when I make an API call and get data of the same format and push it to the list of data i'm passing to the react-table the table does not render it. Please help me identify the issue. Cheers

Setting up the columns:

```
    columns: [
      {
        Header: "Employee ID",
        accessor: "EmployeeID"
      },
      {
        Header: "First Name",
        accessor: "FirstName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Last Name",
        accessor: "LastName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Date of Birth",
        accessor: "DateOfBirth",
      },
      {
        Header: "Status",
        accessor: "Status",
      },
      {
        Header: "Gender",
        accessor: "Gender",
      },
      {
        Header: "UpdatedDateUTC",
        accessor: "UpdatedDateUTC",
      }
    ]
```

What the data looks like:

```
{"EmployeeID":"63c571b3-bff0-4ce1-94f7-255c235580fa","FirstName":"Clive","LastName":"Thomas","Status":"ACTIVE","DateOfBirth":"/Date(697248000000+0000)/","Gender":"M","UpdatedDateUTC":"/Date(1533706298000+0000)/"}
```

My API call and how I'm saving the data item to state. (I console logged the value of the data I'm getting and it is in the correct format)

```
fetch('http://localhost:3100/employees')
      .then((resp) => {
        return resp.json()
      })
      .then((data) => {
        let temp = this.state.posts;
        temp.push(data.Employees[1])
        this.setState({posts: temp})
        console.log(this.state.posts)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error, "catch the hoop")
      })
```

The state and the 'posts' list storing the posts in state at bottom (with dummy data):

```
state = {
    title: "Choose an Endpoint",
    activeOrg: "Orginisation",
    isExpanded: false,
    activeLink: 0,
    authLink:'',
    response: '',
    post: '',
    responseToPost: '',
    show: false,
    modalContent:"",
    token:'',
    verifier:'',
    org:'',
    orginisations: [
      { id: 1, name: "ANU"},
      { id: 2, name: "Bar"},
      { id: 3, name: "FANG"},
      { id: 4, name: "Atlassian"}
    ],
    list: [
      { id: 1, name: "Employees" },
      { id: 2, name: "Leave Applications" },
      { id: 3, name: "Pay Items" },
      { id: 4, name: "Payroll Calendars" },
      { id: 5, name: "Pay Runs" },
      { id: 6, name: "Pay Slips" },
      { id: 7, name: "Settings" },
      { id: 8, name: "Superfund Products" },
      { id: 9, name: "Timesheets" }
    ],
    columns: [
      {
        Header: "Employee ID",
        accessor: "EmployeeID"
      },
      {
        Header: "First Name",
        accessor: "FirstName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Last Name",
        accessor: "LastName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Date of Birth",
        accessor: "DateOfBirth",
      },
      {
        Header: "Status",
        accessor: "Status",
      },
      {
        Header: "Gender",
        accessor: "Gender",
      },
      {
        Header: "UpdatedDateUTC",
        accessor: "UpdatedDateUTC",
      }
    ],
    posts: [
      {"EmployeeID":"63c571b3-bff0-4ce1-94f7-255c235580fa","FirstName":"Clive","LastName":"Thomas","Status":"ACTIVE","DateOfBirth":"/Date(697248000000+0000)/","Gender":"M","UpdatedDateUTC":"/Date(1533706298000+0000)/"}
    ]
  }
```

Render function:

```
render() {
    let myClass=""
    let EndpointList = (
      <div>
        {this.state.list.map((i) => {
          i.id === this.state.activeLink ? myClass="endpoint activeLink" : myClass="endpoint"
          return <Endpoint 
            key={i.id}
            name={i.name}
            myClass={myClass}
            clicked={(event) => this.handleClickEndpoint(i, i.id)}/>
        })}
        </div>
    );
    let orgContainer = ""
    this.state.isExpanded ? orgContainer="orgItem expanded" : orgContainer="orgItem notExpanded"
    let OrgList = (
      <div className={orgContainer}>
        {this.state.orginisations.map((o) => {
          return <Orginisation
            key={o.id}
            name={o.name}
            clicked={(event) => this.handleClickOrg(o,o.id)}
          ></Orginisation>
        })}
      </div>
    );
    var activeContent=<ReactTable columns={this.state.columns} data={this.state.posts} noDataText={"Loading..."}></ReactTable>
    // const columns = Object.keys(this.state.data[0]).map((key, id)=>{
    //   console.log(key)
    //   return {
    //     Header: key,
    //     accessor: key,
    //   }
    // })
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route path='/' exact render={
          () => {
            return (
              <div className='authenticateContainer'>

                <a href={this.state.authLink} className='fill-div'>Click to Auntheticate</a> 
              </div>
            )
          }
        }/>
        <Route path='/home' render={
          () => {
            return (
              <div>
                <div className='sideBar'>
                  <div className='logoHolder'>
                    <img className='logo' alt='Logo' src={'./Assets/logo.png'}></img>
                  </div>
                  {EndpointList}
                  {OrgList}
                  <div style={{}} className="org button" onClick={this.expandOrg}>
                    <img className="orgLogo" alt='Logo' src={'./Assets/orgLogo.png'}></img>
                    {this.state.activeOrg}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="container" id={this.state.title}>
                  {/* <button onClick={() => { this.setCredentials() }}>CLICK ME</button> */}
                  <div className="contentContainer">
                    <div className="head">
                      {this.state.title}
                    </div>
                    {activeContent}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          }
        } />

      </Router> 
    );
  }
}
```

Instantiating the react-table (also in render function above):

```
var activeContent=<ReactTable columns={this.state.columns} data={this.state.posts} noDataText={"Loading..."}></ReactTable>
```

I have also printed the dummy data that is successfully being inserted into the list as well as the API data which is not. As you can see they are clearly identical:
[image: Item 0 is the dummy data and item 1 is the API response data]

Comment: What does your state look like?

Comment: Are you rendering activeContent in your render? can you share the whole component?

Comment: I have updated the question @cullanrocks

Comment: I am just rendering active content in my render method in App.js @Avanthika

Comment: I still would like to see your full initial state. I can't tell if maybe there's an issue with that.

Comment: I added full state @cullanrocks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will resolve your issue, but IMO you should refactor this to be

```
fetch('http://localhost:3100/employees')
      .then((resp) => {
        return resp.json()
      })
      .then((data) => {
        let temp = [...this.state.posts]
        temp.push(data.Employees[1])
        this.setState({
            posts: temp,
            data: data
        })
        console.log(this.state.posts) //this will not have the newest values yet, setState is async
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error, "catch the hoop")
      })
```

It's not good practice to perform manipulations on react state

Comment: that line setting the the state of 'data' was actually copied over from boiler plate code. Deleted now. But thank you for posting an 'answer' that does not answer the question.

Comment: if using sample data works fine, and your actual data is formatted exactly the same, then the first thing you should check (with a debugger) is that state is being set how you want. The other potential issue is the way you render (most importantly when that activeContent var gets set), but you didnt include the render function, just 1 line. unfortunately you havent given enough information to just "answer" your question

Comment: i didnt include that so it would be easier to read but there added

Answer (score 0):

Why are you pushing Employees[1]? That would be the second record.